# Reading password protected worksheet (version - excel 95,97-2003) Java

Tags: java, excel, encryption, apache-poi, worksheet

I have a password protected worksheet create with excel 95,97-2003

i have the password and i was trying to read this file in different ways

**Method 1:**

```
WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream, "password");
throws:  org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: HSSF does not currently support CryptoAPI encryption
```

**Method 2:**

```
    protected InputStream WorkbookProtectionUnlocker(NPOIFSFileSystem fs, String password) throws AAAAException {

    EncryptionInfo info;
    try {
        info = new EncryptionInfo(fs.getRoot());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AAAException(e.getCause());
    }

    Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
```

org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: HSSF does not currently support CryptoAPI encryption

also throw the same exception

**Method 3:**

```
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypto.Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("password");

Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file);
```

same exception .

**Method 4**:

read about `jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook` 
but in this object the password is only allowed setting it to the sheet not the entire worksheet .

throw this error: `jxl.read.biff.PasswordException`

since its not possible setting the password to the worksheet .

**method 5**

```
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypto.Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(fileInfo.getFileOptions().xlsWorkbookPasswordExpression);
                            WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(fileInfo.getInputFile()));
```

the same exception:

```
    org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: HSSF does not currently support CryptoAPI encryption
```

what is the correct way of Opening HSSF workbook which is password protected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache POI does not yet fully support all the different cryptography functionality of the Office file formats, see http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html for the currently supported things.

However there were some enhancement done on trunk since the last release POI-3.15, so it might be worthwhile to try a recent nightly build from https://builds.apache.org/view/POI/job/POI/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/ to see if that makes it work.

Otherwise you will need to report a bug at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/ with a sample file that can be used to reproduce and verify this.

Comment: For completeness this was filled under [#60347](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60347)